# How can I disable the ListView item on long click

Tags: android, listview

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listview;
    String[] subjects = new String[] {"Android","PHP","Blogger","WordPress","SEO"};
    List<String> subject_list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        subject_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(subjects));

        arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subject_list);

        listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                subject_list.remove(position);

                arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Here I had program of deleting item from list view by long click, instead of deleting item have to disable item by long clicking on the item in the `ListView`.

Comment: have you tried view.setEnabled(false); within onItemLongClick()?

Comment: can u plzz modify and edit it

Comment: public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {                                                                     view .setEnabled(false)                                      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code like below

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //subject_list.remove(position);

                if(!view.isEnabled()){
                    return false;
                }
                view.setEnabled(false);
                view.setClickable(false);

                arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }

        });
```

> As listview is replaced with RecyclerView, so i recommend you to use RecyclerView in future or with this.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: yes but i am trying to connect with you on stackoverflow chat room

Comment: but unable to find you, can you find me over there?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 subject_list.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);
```

:) :)

Comment: tnqq so much for ur response

Comment: An answer should be more than code, it should include an explanation why it is suitable and appropriate. You want to educate so the OP knows what to do in the future, not just solve this particular problem.